# Prove $\forall n \in N$, every set of natural numbers of size n has a maximum element. May assume that sets do not repeat numbers.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Prove using induction.

So i'm a bit confused about how to do this question. My attempt at it seems like i'm missing a lot and it looked to easy.

```
Base cases:
P(1) = {1} = 1
P(2) = {1,2} = 2 is the largest 
P(3) = {1,2,3} = 3 is the largest
P(4) = {1,2,3,4} = 4 is the largest.
```

Assume that n $\ge$ 1, and the set of size n has a maximum element. (induction hypothesis)

P(n+1) = {{P(n)}, n+1} since the set of size n is included just before n+1 in the set of size n+1, we know that n is the largest element in the set of size n by the induction hypothesis, and n+1 > n. So n+1 is the largest element in the set. So this is true.

Is there anything wrong with what i did?

Comment: Yes, you only considered the sets $\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\}$ instead of *any* subset of size $n$.

Comment: I'm not understanding why I need that. Isn't it enough for the base cases and from that n is the largest element in the set of natural numbers of size n?

Comment: You're supposed to prove that *every* set of size (for example) 3 has a maximum element.  So your proof should also cover the fact that the set $\{1, 17, 109033745\}$ has a maximum element.  How does your proposed proof address that case? It only seems to discuss sets that look like $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, and  $\{1, 17, 109033745\}$ is not of that type.

Comment: Ok ..then i'm really confused. So how would i address that in my base case if there are essentially an infinite number of combinations for a set of size n>1? Would i just say that there HAS to be some number bigger than others because we assume that numbers aren't repeated?

Comment: Are you required to use induction or was that just your try? Can you use the well-ordering principle?

Comment: It was a past test question and the start of the question is: prove using induction. We've went over well ordering so i'm sure he'd say to use well ordering if he wanted it like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should induct on the size, $n$.

First prove that *all size-$1$ subsets of $\mathbb{N}$* have a maximal element. This is straightforward, since their maximal element is simply their only element. That was the base case of your induction proof.

Now, for the inductive step. Suppose that all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that have $n$ elements have maximal elements. Consider a general subset of size $n+1$. Call it $A$. Pick an arbitrary element of $A$, call it $a$.

Note that $A$ is the union of some $n$-element subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{a\}$. Call this $n$-element subset $B$. Note that $a \not\in B$ (otherwise $A$ would only have $n$ elements). By your assumption, $B$ must have a maximal element. Call that $b$.

By trichotomy (which is probably one of the axioms you're allowed to assume for this, in some equivalent form), exactly one of the following is true:

- $a < b$
- $a > b$
- $a = b$

The third statement can't be true, because we know $a \not\in B$. If the first statement is true, then $b$ is the maximal element of $A$. If the second statement is true, then $a$ is the maximal element of $A$. Either way, $A$ has a maximal element, so this completes your inductive step.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to label the inductive hypothesis explicitly, so that OP can be sure what it is and when it is used?

Comment: The inductive hypothesis is this: "If all $n$-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ have a maximal element, then all $(n+1)$-element subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ have a maximal element."

Comment: No, the inductive hypothesis is “All subsets of $\Bbb N$ that have $n$ elements have maximal elements.” You said it yourself; it is the second sentence of paragraph 3.  Except that it should be ‘maximum’, not ‘maximal’.

Comment: What is what I said called? Because that's what I thought the inductive step was? ... EDIT: Sorry, I will label it explicitly and change maximal to maximum (but what is the difference?) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element

Comment: I don't know, but it's not a hypothesis; it's what is required to be proved.

Comment: For the case of subsets of $\Bbb N$, ‘maximal element’ and ‘maximum element’ are equivalent.  But since the OP's task is to prove that  every finite subset of $\Bbb N$ has a *maximum* element, that's what you should prove, and not something similar that is not exactly the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, but these complaints seem a bit pedantic. Doron Zeilberger would be annoyed at you :)

Comment: Thanks i understood what you said. It's too bad I would have never thought about saying that "A is the union of some n element subset of N" and that the arbitrary a is not an element of B...:( My mind isn't creative enough for this course.